# Under what conditions can Unity delete an object / null a pointer?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

Recently I get (apparently random) MissingReferenceExceptions and NullReferenceExceptions. I managed to narrow it down to two variables going missing (plus any other references to their content).

I double checked all lines that reference those variables, none of them delete or null anything. I've also checked places where the values escape to, but this shouldn't really matter, since c# is garbage collected (anyway, they don't delete anything either). By the way, those objects are created via new, and they are neither GameObjects nor MonoBehaviours (but one of them is a List that contains MonoBehaviours). They are not referenced by instance variables of MonoBehaviours that get Destroyed either. They are/were still referenced by other instance variables of course, otherwise the exception couldn't be thrown.

Ok, I'm not pasting my 3000+ lines of code. Also, I'm not asking where the error is but rather how to look for it: under what conditions does unity delete objects / null references to them?

```
NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object
        Level.WipeMoveable (Boolean keepAvailable) (at Assets/scripts/Level.cs:220)
        Level.HandleRightClick (UnityEngine.GameObject clicked) (at Assets/scripts/Level.cs:184)
        Selectable.OnClick (Int32 button) (at Assets/scripts/Selectable.cs:35)
        Clickable.ButtonReleased (Int32 button) (at Assets/scripts/Clickable.cs:35)
        Clickable.OnMouseOver () (at Assets/scripts/Clickable.cs:56)
```

The expected output is the objects and references remaining intact, the actual output are NullReferenceExceptions and MissingReferenceExceptions (occasionally; most of the time I get the expected output)

Comment: obvious answers is either it never got set, or it got destroyed. or in the case of a click it could be that the event onclick never checked nothing was assigned to happen

Comment: It did get set, I checked that, and it did get destroyed/nulled. What I'm asking is how I can find the place where it got destroyed. And the question is that ridiculously long because otherwise I wouldn't have been allowed to post it

Comment: You could add an ondestroy to it to see when it gets called, but cant help without code and reproduce possibilities, only you can see your code, so without an idea of what is even the thing and what you might do with it.. it could be it gets destroyed and left over things that frame try to access it who knows..

Comment: did that, and got a single line stack-trace containing only the Finalize. (didn't manage to get a MonoBehaviour destroyed again so far)

Comment: problem is, the ondestroy wouldnt tell you what or who told it.. Id find all the destroys and get them printing the name func + name of what its going to destroy so you can see, who calls it, and then if necessary, put a break in and attach vs to unity so you can see more

Comment: Hey there. Unity will destroy an UnityEngine.Object in following cases: 1) Destroy/DestroyImmediate is called directly on this object. 2) It is a component of a GO and GO was destroyed. 3) Parent GO was destroyed 4)  Another scene was loaded (non-addictively).

Comment: It can be nasty to debug (and it's hard to speculate), but I would recommend you to dig for two cases: 1) Breakpoint all the Destroy(Immediate) invocations 2) Check if it happens only after the scene has changed.

Comment: Quick possible solution, you can try with VS2019. They introduced data breakpoints for C#, so you may start the debugger and monitor one of the references to those objects, and the debugger will stop at the line after the one that changes the value.

Comment: the one reproducible case I found so far is the objects are destroyed when the game recompiles while still running (it's otherwise still responsive afterwards though and most objects are left intact)

Comment: My Visual Studio licence expired some time ago, so I can't try with VS2019 (currently using MoneDevelop). Anyway, I made a function that checks all objects i know to occasionally go missing and throws if they are missing. Calling that from a lot of places does work to an extent, but so far the bug doesn't appear to come from a single source (except the recompile)